# Employer modifying verbal agreement

Tags: job-offer, united-kingdom

I found an internal vacancy at my company and contacted the manager of the team (Steve) to have an informal discussion about the job, the team, etc.
Realizing it was a good fit, we had more formal interviews and ultimately talked about my expectations. After following up with his manager (Kevin) and HR, he came back to me with an offer. We had several back and forth regarding the compensation mostly, which was always approved by Kevin and HR. I finally officially accepted the offer.

Two days later, Kevin contacted me to inform me that, although we had a verbal agreement, some internal policies prevent me to obtain the title and compensation we agreed on. Apparently, Kevin was not aware of my current situation during the negotiation and the new contract would be too big of a gap.
However, the new job is in a different department, where hours, pressure and responsibilities are much higher. In any other company, the compensation gap would have been even bigger. But it didn't matter for them. They plan to give me another offer sometime this week.

I don't think they are allowed to change a verbal agreement based on those reasons, isn't it?
Is there anything I can do? Or anything I should do?
Being an internal, what would be the risk/reward for me to start a legal procedure?

N.B.: All the discussions above have been done over video calls, so I have no written proof.

Comment: It's about what you can prove in court. A verbal agreement is going to count for very little when it comes to proof.

Comment: A verbal agreement without a witness it pretty much useless.

Comment: Welcome new user. Very unfortunately, there is no such thing as a verbal "agreement" or a verbal "offer".  Indeed, it's important to note that **you yourself** are not in any way bound.  Say they came back with an actual offer (ie, a written executed contract, there is no other "offer") and then **you yourself** didn't want to do it (perhaps you decide to move on to another company .. whatever), that is completely OK.  There is absolutely no "offer" or "agreement" until it is an executed legal document.

Comment: If Kevin verbally acknowledged the original number really had existed, the first thing to do get an email stream going that puts his verbal acknowledgment in writing. That establishes that they believed that it was worth paying you that much. Whatever comes later can build on that. As Fattie says, "internal policy" is fluff. Unless it is a govt position with pay capped by law, they can make a "market adjustment" at any time, or invent some other verbiage to the same effect. If you take less than the agreed-upon number, there is a likelyhood that you will get the same behavior from them later.

Comment: I don't know where people get this idea that a verbal offer isn't legally binding. It very may well be legally binding, but only an attorney can tell you if it is in your specific case. So you have several possible choices; reject their offer, accept their offer, or contact an attorney and pursue a legal remedy. Each choice brings it's own set of risks.

Comment: And in the future, never accept an offer too prematurely, it makes you look desperate. Only make your decision when you have the contract in hand (that and a copy of the employee manual if it's mentioned in the contract).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That verbal agreement may as well be not written on toilet paper...

Your choice to accept the new written offer or not.

When considering, just think about how they behave with all of these negotiations. Do they pull the same stunt often? If they do, then it may be better to look elsewhere.

Comment: “That verbal agreement may as well be not written on toilet paper...” - What?

Comment: Toilet paper is a perfectly fine medium for receiving written text as long as you respect the environment under which it retains its integrity.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't think they are allowed to change a verbal agreement based on those reasons, isn't it?

They most likely are. If you want to be absolutely sure you need to talk to a lawyer that know your local labor laws.

> Is there anything I can do?

There are plenty of things you CAN do

1. Explore legal options
2. Refuse the transfer under the changed condition and stick with your current role
3. Quit
4. Try to negotiate. Assuming that this was an honest mistake on Kevin's part you can discuss what it would take to get you to the originally agreed upon title and compensation. Map out a plan and discuss how you can fast-track this process. Maybe there are some other perks they can throw in as a bridge measure.

> Or anything I should do? Being an internal,

I would start with option 4 above.

> what would be the risk/reward for me to start a legal procedure?

Any type of legal action is pretty much guaranteed to end your career at this company. You may not outright get fired, but you will get shut aside and most likely "managed out the door". That's technically illegal but also impossible to prove if it's done properly. If word gets out, it may have significant impact on finding other employment: suing your employer is a huge red flag.

Answer (score 0):

To simply repeat what everyone else has said:

There is simply no such thing as a "verbal agreement". There's no such thing as a "verbal offer".

An "agreement" literally means a contract, and an "offer" literally means an offer. (IE, executed by a company officer.)

*{Aside - it's worth noting that *even if something is **written down on physical paper** that means, literally: nothing*. It's not a contract, offer or anything else. It is a ............ "piece of paper". It's "a note passed in class." A contract is only a contract if it is executed legally, by a germane party, in the manner proscribed in your legal jurisdiction.  A "piece of paper with some writing on it" is just a "piece of paper with some writing on it".}*

The situation is this:

- So far you have had interesting talks and discussions about certain issues.
- Eventually you will be made an offer.

It looks like they have made you an offer and unfortunately it's no good.

Are you looking for your "next language" to respond?

If so,

> "Dear team, thanks for the written offer, March 12th, which includes a salary of $88,888 units. In fact during our pre-offer discussions, the salary number was $99,999. Can you offer me an offer at $99,999?

Note that

1. It's completely pointless being other than blunt.  Just state (as in my example) "Can you offer me an offer at $99,999?"  You're dealing with professional negotiators, any "arguments" you present are literally a waste of ascii, like air in a wind.
2. Here's an important point.  You see where you said:

> "Kevin said ... some internal policies prevent me to obtain the title and compensation we agreed on"

Technically, in negotiations analysis, this is known by the technical term "humorous bullshit".

OF COURSE they are not going to say:

> "We will only give you $X"

What they will say is

> "[*insert some total bullshit here, pick any random bullshit, because it is totally, completely, irrelevant bullshit - it is literally just random-word-filler*] and for that reason we will only give you $X"

Do you get my point?  Have you ever had to turn down someone for a date .. you don't just say "No.", you say something like "Oh, sorry, it's not possible that night, so no thanks."

Regarding the specific humorous bullshit:

> " some internal policies prevent me to obtain the title and compensation we agreed on"

it means utterly nothing, it is random words.  "Filler."

They're just saying "they won't give you what you wanted."

Your response, as above, is simply

> "... during our pre-offer discussions, the salary number was $99,999. Can you offer me an offer at $99,999?

Comment: Not that it probably helps the OP, but in UK law (where the OP is) verbal agreements do exist. See https://londonlawpractice.com/how-to-enforce-a-verbal-contract/ for example.

Comment: You are probably right about the BS. Just one clarification. They didn't pull the "internal policy" flag during the negotiation to justify a lower than expected compensation. They used it two days after I accepted their offer. But I agree, this offer most likely means nothing. And it might just be a dirty negotiation technique.

Comment: It means nothing, and it's just a "negotiating tactic".  I really wouldn't go so far as to say "tactic".  It really is just a random polite phrase, inserted before "we offer you $X".

Comment: @mattfreake that's sort of correct.  But unfortunately "verbal agreements" can be trivially and instantly dismissed by saying "oh we were just talking". Note too that the OP was *not even* talking to a germane party. (An actual company officer who could even make such an offer.)  It was nothing more than "talk".

Comment: @fattie if that were true, no verbal agreement would ever be legally enforced. The person who wanted to break it would just say "we were just talking", end of story. Your overall advice is correct, but what you are saying about verbal agreements is misleading.

Comment: `There is simply no such thing as a "verbal agreement"` - There absolutely is a the notion of a "verbal agreement" in civil law, however, you must prove that verbal agreement actually exists.  Often a Judge in a courtroom, will determine if a reasonable person, would have concluded that a "agreement" would exist or not.

Comment: matt and donald . ...   sticking to the actual situation ... the overwhelming point is the OP was talking to a janitor or programming lead or such. ("Steve" I believe.)   it's not even in the ballpark that this could in any way be considered even vaguely some sort of "agreement".    how can you have an "agreement" with a non-germane, non-authority?

Comment: I agree, but the answer went beyond that though with simply untrue statements like 'There is simply no such thing as a "verbal agreement".' Others beyond the OP will read the answer and it is important that it is all correct, not just the spirit of it.